# Blender error "Invalid clnors in this fan!"

Tags: python, blender

When applying a modifier via the python API to an object the log message "Invalid clnors in this fan!" is shown multiple times.

1. What are clnors?
2. What is the meaning of the log message?
3. How can the error be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

'clnors' is 'custom loop normals'. As I found [here](http://flogger-k.blogspot.ru/2015/08/blog-post_12.html)  this error is shown, well, when there are invalid normals, but it's trying to fix it (code [here](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-blender-cvs/2014-August/066655.html)). If everything is working seems like you can ignore the error.